# Innodb rename table cause relationship issues

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have to perform some alter operations on large innodb table I found the best to create a table like the old table and then alter it. I now found that all tables are still referring to old table. To understand fully my question please consider following queries

```
CREATE table books2 LIKE books;
ALTER TABLE `books2` DROP `not_needed_fields`;
INSERT INTO books2 (fields) SELECT fields FROM books;
RENAME TABLE books TO old_books;
RENAME TABLE books2 TO books;
```

All foreign keys of book_id is showing relationship with old_books I want to change it to books table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should recreate FK, e.g. -

```
-- Drop FK that refers to old_books
ALTER TABLE child_table
  DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_books;

-- Add new FK
ALTER TABLE child_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_books FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
    REFERENCES books(book_id);
```